# QSortFilterProxyModel Filter Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt5, pyqt5

Using a QSortFilterProxyModel I need to filter the data based on the value of a specific column; however, the column may contain multiple values.  I need to NOT show the row if the column contains a specific value.  Do I need to subclass the QSortFilterProxyModel and override the filterAcceptsRow() method or should I use a setFilterRegExp?

The column can contain integers: 0,1,2,3.  If the column contains a 2 then I need to not show the row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store data as a QList or list you can easily subclass QSortFilterProxyModel to check this list in every row

Here is a simple example:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QSortFilterProxyModel,Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QListView, QApplication

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
list = QListView()
list.setWindowTitle('sample')
list.setMinimumSize(600, 400)

model = QStandardItemModel(list)

for i in range(1, 10):
    # create each item with a list attached to the Qt::UserRole + 1
    item = QStandardItem(str(i))
    item.setData([i, i*2],  Qt.UserRole + 1)
    model.appendRow(item)

class MyFilterModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
        i =  self.sourceModel().index(source_row, 0, source_parent)
        data = self.sourceModel().data(i, Qt.UserRole + 1)
        print(data)
        return 2 not in data

filter_model = MyFilterModel()
filter_model.setSourceModel(model)

list.setModel(filter_model)
list.show()
app.exec()
```

You can even customize your filter model to accepts a lambda filter function

Comment: Thanks jgoday.  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you should subclass the QSortFilterProxyModel and override the filterAcceptsRow(), here bellow is a simple proxy model for table model:

```
class DemoProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    """

    """
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, sourceRow, sourceParent):
        """custom filtering"""
        if not self.filterRegExp().isEmpty():
            model_source = self.sourceModel()
            if model_source is None:
                return False
            
            # pick up the column that you want to filter, e.g., column 3
            index0 = model_source.index(sourceRow, 3, sourceParent)
            data0 = model_source.data(index0)

            # return self.filterRegExp() == data_type  # equal match, the tight binding
            return self.filterRegExp().indexIn(data0) >= 0  # include match, the loose binding
            # return data_type.__contains__(self.filterRegExp())  # include match, the loose binding

        # parent call for initial behaviour
        return super().filterAcceptsRow(sourceRow, sourceParent)
```